# Docker use variables in conf file?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, hostname

If I'm using Docker with nginx for hosting a web app, how can I use either

1. Variables in my `docker-compose.yml` file
2. Environment variables such as `HOSTNAME=example.com`.

So that when I build the container, it will insert the value into my nginx.conf file that I copy over when I build the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables is your compose file. According to official docs

> Your configuration options can contain environment variables. Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which docker-compose is run. For example, suppose the shell contains POSTGRES_VERSION=9.3 and you supply this configuration:
>
> `db:   image: "postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}"`

When you run docker-compose up with this configuration, Compose looks for the POSTGRES_VERSION environment variable in the shell and substitutes its value in.

See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) for more information. You will find various other approaches to supply environment variables in the link like passing them through `env_file` etc.